# Pegar um determinado valor dentro de um MenuFlyout do WindowsPhone

Tags: listview, windows-phone

Estou com uma duvida em WP8. Tenho um listView e dentro dele tenho um MenuFlyout , minha duvida é como faço para pegar o valor de uma determinada coluna depois do click ser feito no MenuFlyout. Segue o codigo:

```
    <ListView  x:Name="listaCliente" ItemsSource="{Binding Cliente}" Background="Black"  Margin="0,34,9.833,33.833" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Holding="ListViewItem_Holding" >
                                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                            <MenuFlyout>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem Name="menuLigarDt" Text="Ligar" Click="CMLIGAR" />
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Localizar" />
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Mensagem" />
                                            </MenuFlyout>
                                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>   
                                        <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding razao}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <Run Text=" - " FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding fantasia}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" Foreground="White" />
                                    <LineBreak/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Rodrigo seu código não aparece.

Comment: Estranho... Mas vou copiar novamente. Ficou da mesma forma como sou novato no stackoverflow nãos sei se estou fazendo algo errado, apenas copiei e colei o codigo

Comment: esta aparecendo agora ?